# Use inheritance or code different USART variants

Tags: c++, embedded, dma, usart

I have a USART class that transmits data using the tx interrupt.
Now I want to create a variant that uses DMA to transmit data.
What would you prefer:

- use inheritance to create two USART subclasses, e.g. ISRUSART, and DMAUSART?

or

- just implement a variant check in the code. Let the user specify in the constructor if dma should be enabled and then perform checks in the code to decide what to do (enable interrupt or load dma)?

Comment: Inheritance is a needlessly expensive version of *bool* here.  Painful for client code to use as well, this would be a config setting.  If you don't know which one is "best" then how could the client programmer possibly know?

Answer (score 2):

This can't trivially be answered. As with so many design decisions it is a case of "the devil is in the detail". So my answer here isn't going to be "go with solution A" or "go with solution B", but rather "What you need to look at to decide which way to go" - as this will also help you more than just giving a straight "You should choose answer A", since it guides you through the process, and you can use this process for future design decisions too.

The main questions are:

1. How different is the code?
2. How will it be used?
3. What are the benefits of one solution over another?
4. What are the drawback of one solution over another?

You are the only one that can answer these sort of questions, because we don't have your code, and we don't know the hardware you are working on.

To clarify the points above:

If the code difference between "with DMA" and "without DMA" is very minimal, and can be added with just a couple of if's in the right places, then that's probably the right solution. On the other hand, if there are many places that are quite different, then clearly that's a good argument for splitting the code up to make it clearer.

How the code is used is also a critical question for the design. You need to determine where and how the DMA vs. interrupt choice is made, and where it is placed. Is it a factory function that then initializes the correct derived class from a `class BaseSerial`. There may also

The "Benefits vs Drawbacks" is probably fairly obvious. But without knowing what your code is like at present, and what the differences will be, it's hard to say what is gained and lost from each of the choices.

In general, having a common interface/base-class, and then a derived class seems like a reasonable solution. But if it's not done right, then this can be at least as confusing and complicated as using "more basic" approach and have two sets of code.

Naturally, one has to also consider performance. If you add extra layers (that actually are generated in the code, and not optimised out), then that may affect the overall performance of the device, as would "unnecessary if/else" statements. Again, without understanding the details of the actual design, it's hard to say what solution is better from a performance perspective too.

It is possibly a good idea to experiment and make a prototype with what you think is the right solution, see how that "looks" and "feels", and if it's likely to be right, then go for it. If it "feels wrong", then go back and look at another solution. Repeat until you either come up with a good solution, or are forced to choose the least bad because you are running out of time....